# auto-execute method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, automation

how could i have the web server execute a certain method on the 1st of each month at 10am? and if the server is down at that time, what could be a way to ensure that the method executes when the server returns..

any thoughts would be appreciated..

EDIT: yeah, windows server

Comment: Windows server or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(VS.85).aspx) seems like a good option for this.

Comment: neat. did not know there was an API.